# C: function name vs. function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I am curious how C handle the function name. To be specific, is the function name a pointer to the beginning address of the function body, like array name is? If that is the case, when assign a value to function pointer, why people sometimes apply reference & to the function name like:

```
int foo(int a, int b);
int (*p_func)(int a, int b) = &foo;
```

I know that we can directly assign foo to p_func without reference. But it underlying does implicit conversion to retrieve the function pointer and then assign to p_func. So seems like there is difference between function name and function pointer. Then what is it?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no difference. The standard says that `foo` is the same as `&foo` in that context.

Comment: There is no such thing as reference in C.

Comment: Neither an array name nor a function name is a pointer. An expression of array or pointer type (including the name of an array object or of a pointer) is implicitly *converted* to a pointer (to the array's first element or to the pointer, respectively) in most but not all contexts.

Comment: @KeithThompson: And an expression that is an id-expression that names a function decays to a pointer to that function in most (but not all) cases...

Comment: @KeithThompson so in what context, function name is different from the pointer to the function?

Comment: @KerrekSB: What is an "id-expression"? And yes, I meant to say "(to the array's first element or to the function, respectively)".

Comment: @Guoqin: If `func` is a function name and `ptr` is a function pointer, `sizeof ptr` yields the size of the pointer, but `sizeof func` is illegal. Also, `&func` yields a pointer to the function, but `&ptr` yields a pointer to the pointer object.

Comment: @KeithThompson: It's just the term for an expression that just consists of an identifier, like `foo` in the OP's code.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The C standard doesn't use the term *id-expression*, and the rule applies to *any* expression of function type (such as `*func_ptr`).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Ah, indeed, good point.